# Are .d.ts files required to use export statements if published to npm?

Tags: typescript, npm, export

I have an application, parts of which I want to reuse in another project. Application has a lot of interfaces defined in the .d.ts file, which are globally visible. As a simplified example, I have typings.d.ts file with an interface:

```
interface Something {
    thing: string
}
```

then I have a component using that interface:

```
export function setSomething(input: Something){
    input.thing = 'thing';
}
```

which is then later used in a project. It's all working fine in this application, but if I publish it to npm and try to import component in another project like this:

```
import {setSomething} from 'ts-test/component';

setSomething({thing: 'nothing'});
```

typescript type check cannot find an interface and reports an error in the component. Changing all interfaces to be exported from a .d.ts file and imported by .ts files seems to fix the problem, but I will have to add import statements to a lot of files, can it be avoided? Why don't parent package autoload type declarations that are autoloaded by a dependency?

I have tried adding `"types": "./types.d.ts",` into package.json, but then type check gives an error that types.d.ts is not a module. I have tried setting several typescript configuration options like `"include": ["*.ts", "typings.d.ts"]`, but those don't seem to affect a project which package is installed into.

Comment: This depends on the tsconfig.json of the project which has installed the package, specifically the `"types"` property of `"compilerOptions"`. However, whether or not you write the types using globals or `import` and `export` ultimately depends on the JavaScript code which the types describe.

Comment: @AluanHaddad According to typescript documentation, `"types"` refers only to packages in `"./node_modules/@types/"`, not to my own package which would be in `"./node_modules/my-package/"`. I guess I can create a separate package with types... Regarding whether globals or import/export is better for a javascript code, I think in my case it pretty much doesn't matter, I just used globally visible definitions for convenience.